# What's the meaning of “vanilla” object list

Tags: django, django-views

In the documentation of Django, I have a confusion about this passage below:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/

> Notice that along with a filtered queryset, we’re also using a custom
>   template name. If we didn’t, the generic view would use the same
>   template as **the “vanilla” object list**, which might not be what we
>   want.

I'm not a native English speaker,so can anybody tell me what the “vanilla” object list is. Thank you very much!

I also want to know what the "ordinary" object list, described as “vanilla” in the Django documentation, is **exactly**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> vanilla - Unexciting, normal, conventional, boring. ([source](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=vanilla))

In your case it means "default" `queryset` value for generic view which will be

```
queryset = Book.objects.all()
```

If you don't specify it explicitly

Read more about "default" `queryset` value here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#viewing-subsets-of-objects

Especially this part

> Specifying `model = Publisher` is really just shorthand for saying `queryset = Publisher.objects.all()`

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "vanilla" means "conventional". In other words, if the `template_name` class attribute was not customized, the `AcmeBookList` generic view would use the same template as the `BookList` generic view.